# Chrome extension cant render css properly

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I am new to creating chrome extensions... I am trying to create a chrome extension that accepts a blacklist containing unproductive website and blocks those pages. I am trying to load a custom page onto those blocked websites however the styling isn't loading properly.

My Content.js (for loading the custom page) :

```js
const generateSTYLES = () => {
  return `<style>@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=opensans:500);
  body {
    background: #4ADEDE;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    max-height: 700px;
  .study {
    font-size: 120px;
    border: 5px solid #FFFF00;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  ._404 {
  font-size: 220px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 250px;
  letter-spacing: 15px;
    `
};

const generateHTML = (pageName) => {
  return `
  <div class='_404'>404</div>
  <p>STUDYING > ${pageName}</p>
   `;
};

switch (window.location.hostname) {
  case "www.facebook.com":
    document.head.innerHTML = generateSTYLES();
    document.body.innerHTML = generateHTML("FACEBOOK");
    break;
  case "www.netflix.com":
    document.head.innerHTML = generateSTYLES();
    document.body.innerHTML = generateHTML("NETFLIX");
    break;
}
```

My manifest.json (config file for extension) :

```
    {
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Clock Hacks",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["Content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "icons": { "48": "icon48.png", "128": "icon128.png" },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "Popup.html",
    "default_title": "Website Blocker"
  }
}
```

It loads like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8At1M.png) even though the font size should be 220px and the text should be in the center of the webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check you closed your **< / style >** and that the last style has this close bracket **}** ?

```
const generateSTYLES = () => {
  return `<style>
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=opensans:500');
  body {
    background: #4ADEDE;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    max-height: 700px;
  }
  .study {
    font-size: 120px;
    border: 5px solid #FFFF00;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  ._404 {
    font-size: 220px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 250px;
    letter-spacing: 15px;
  }
  </style>
    `
};
```

Comment: I hadn't closed the tag but the issue persists even after adding the </style>

Comment: Can you check again? This works fine here https://jsfiddle.net/pL203fg1/